# Add Qty to Product before adding to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, addtocart

I am looking for an event observer which is suitable for my requirements.

My requirement is I add to cart the product but qty I want to add to this cart will be decided by the product attribute.

I will be having a custom attribute called `attribute1` which will have an integer number.

So when I add to cart the product, I will get the attribute and number which is defined in it and I set this number as a qty to the product which is getting added to cart.

So following are the observers I tried, but not getting any success
 `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and I am looking for event something like `checkout_cart_product_add_before` but it seems not their.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you plse check answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sales_quote_product_add_after` event. You can access there the added quote items and change the quantity. Just be careful not to change the quantity for items that have a parent set (you can check if `$item->getParentItem()` is set).

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite `Mage_Checkout_CartController` or check if any third party module have rewrite `Mage_Checkout_CartController` class already then use that class to rewrite,

In `AddAction` function - get `attribute1` value and `setParam` `qty` = `attribute1` of `getRequest`.
Then call - `parent::AddAction();` - So that this wont break the original code of magento.

**Did anyone find my answer useful or not?** Because of **-1** point I can't post answers and questions in other Stack Exchange websites. I'm completely **frustrated** & **stuck** because of this **-1** point. Otherwise I will not come to any Stack Exchange sites any more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code you have used, but it works with `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and set quantity on `$strockItem` instead of `$product`:

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
    $stockItem->setQty($product->getData('attribute1'));
    $stockItem->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best approach is using the `min sale qty` this way the quantity added to the cart will be the value that you have set.